# One-way or return ticket for one year study

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, study, hungary

I am about to study in Hungary this fall and going back home in June next year.

I am Indonesian and Residence permit is needed during my stay in Budapest.
As I am preparing document to apply for a visa, I'd like ask for your suggestion:

1. What kind of flight ticket should I buy? One-way ticket or return.
2. If I buy one-way ticket, is it possible to enter from another Schengen country, and continue my journey to Budapest by land (train or bus) -- Because the ticket is cheaper.
3. If I buy a return ticket, I am still having difficulty in finding a good deal, and I am thinking about having flexible ticket but I am not sure how it works on booking changes.

Comment: You might be better served asking this on [expatriates.se], which is our sister site devoted to long term residency (including University studies).

Comment: @CGCampbell Not sure about that, the question is mostly about the travel aspect. For example, my answer relies on what I know about short-term travel in the Schengen area and about airline reservation systems, and *not* really on what I know about expatriation.

Comment: @CGCampbell I think question number three should be removed, because the topic considered as immigration question.

Comment: @Oscar You can edit your question yourself if you want!

Comment: Your nationality would also be useful to know.

Comment: @CMaster I am Indonesian and I wrote down my nationality up there.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, because it's already June and your stay will be shorter than a year, buying a return ticket might still (barely) be possible but note that airlines everywhere have a one-year booking horizon and/or a limit of one year between departure and return so that it's simply impossible to present a return ticket for a visa lasting one year or more.

So, while I don't know Hungary, I would be really surprised if they required you to buy a ticket in advance. [This brochure from the foreign ministry](http://konzuliszolgalat.kormany.hu/download/8/78/30000/ENTRYFORLONGSTAY20120327.pdf) does not mention any such requirement either. Usually, embassies recommend the opposite. It's only for short-stay visas that you must have very specific travel plans.

Once you have a student visa or residence permit from a Schengen country, you can enter the area through any other country and travel by train or bus if you wish.

Comment: If booking by telephone you can arrange for the return sector to be after the booking window with most airlines. However it will still need to be taken within one year of departure.

Comment: @Calchas Thanks for the precision, I amended the answer.

Comment: @Relaxed That's very true on return ticket based on my experience so far.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Return tickets are usually cheaper than singles. At worse you can throw away the return component. You will have to telephone if you want the return sector to be more than on year away from the booking date, simply because the flights are not loaded in the system yet. Most airlines will allow this though. Presumably you will want to visit your home at some stage (Christmas/birthday/holiday?) so you might want to plan for that.

(4) No matter how flexible the ticket is, the ticket validity period is one year. There is a fee to make a change on most semi-flex tickets. If space is not available in your original booking class there might be a fare difference to pay as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that return tickets are usually cheaper, that's why I prefer return ticket, instead of one-way. But unfortunately, I still couldn't find any good deals for it in any airlines.